# String is one of... convention

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assuming we don't do what I want to do which is to implement `Array.prototype.has()`, what is conventions for the following...

```
if (['contacts','calendar','tasks','inbox'].indexOf(kind)!==-1) {
```

What I don't like is the `!==-1`, but I also don't like the array.

I used to use a `String.prototype.inList(list,<delimiter>)` which would actually compute the delimiter if not provided.

Forgive me for bemoaning the collision of zero-based arrays and truthiness. Is there some sneaky way of doing this without `indexOf` and `!==-1`, I suppose I could say `indexOf(kind)+1` to get the truthiness. What else?

EDIT:
To refine what I am looking for -- is a way to handle "is string in list", but in the literal way (quick, dirty, shorthand) and not so much in the way where `list` is an array, or in a variable like `find.inList(list)`. I am open to prototype solutions, but am more curious about creative hacks like the `~'a b c'.split(' ').indexOf(abc)`. So maybe `String.prototype.hasItem(find,<delimiter>)` so that `'a b c'.hasItem(abc)`

Comment: `if (~[a,b,c].indexOf(d))`, but how about `if ([a,b,c].some(is(d))`, where `is=x=>y=>x===y`

Comment: In ES7 `Array.prototype.includes` exist which will return a boolean. So you don't have to use `.indexOf() !== -``. Polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill

Comment: This is also the behavior of the indexof type operator in.a number of other languages. its a well established convention

Comment: @Edwin `includes` ?? they must be giving `getElementsByTagName` a run for their money. I am surprised they didn't name it `isContainingMemberLike`

Comment: What do you mean? it's on the `Array.prototype` it was called contains before but now includes because of certain library problems.

Comment: @Edwin - why don't you write your comment as an answer?

Comment: Because it's not an answer, I'm letting him know that `includes` is coming in the near future. And I'm not sure how to answer his String delimiter thing.

Comment: @Edwin Yes, I was just making fun of the choice of `includes` vs just plain `has`. I have clarified the question with an Edit.

Comment: @MarkRobbins Did you take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrote this a long time ago, idk if this helps. (Rewritten in ES6 arrow functions are commented out)

```
Array.prototype.includes = function(element) {
    return this.some(function(el) {
        return (typeof el == "string") ? el.includes(element) : el === element;
    });
    // ES6 Arrow Functions
    // return this.some(el => (typeof el == "string") ? el.includes(element) : el === element);
}

String.prototype.containsAll = function(arr, index){
    return arr.every(function(el){
        return this.includes(el, index);
    }, this);
    // ES6 Arrow Functions
    // return arr.every(el => this.includes(el, index), this);
}

String.prototype.contains = function(arr, index) {
    return arr.some(function(el){
        return this.includes(el, index);
    }, this);
    // ES6 Arrow Functions
    // return arr.some(el => this.includes(el, index), this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn the array into an object with the array members as keys, and values of anything (true) .

Then you can do "if (kind in obj)"

Also has the nice advantage of a O(1) lookup time instead of O(n)